# TextView.getAlpha doesnt exist in Android

Tags: android, textview

I want to get current alpha of textview i am using the following code but i am getting an error that

```
                java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.getAlpha
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method since API Level 11. Check your API version.

Comment: Yes i think its an api issue i had 8

Answer (score 3):

`View.getAlpha()` only exists since API level 11. You are trying to running your code on a too-old version of Android.

If you absolutely require this functionality, then update your app's `minSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to prevent it running on older Android versions. If you can live without it, do a runtime check to see if the API level is high enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Alpha method like below

```
           Textview tv_password;
           tv_password =(TextView) findviewById(R.id.tv1);
           tv_password.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```

you can't use getAlpha() method with Textview

Answer (score 0):

`View.getAlpha()` available from API level 11.But if you want to use this on older api then you may use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library available for using the [Honeycomb (Android 3.0) animation API](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html) on all versions of the platform back to 1.0!

So use need to change for e.g.

```
mAlpha = mView.getAlpha();
```

to

```
mAlpha = ViewHelper.getAlpha(mView);
```

where `mView` is your view.

Note : Don't forget to import `com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;`